# Obfuscating uploaded document URLs in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

Users upload private documents to my site using the carrierwave gem. By default carrierwave accesses the images based on a database ID, this makes it very easy for other to guess the urls of documents they should not have access to.

I would like to make the documents more secure by obfiscating their URLs to make accessing documents by guessing urls impossible.

How would I go about doing this please?

Comment: Use uuid's as identification for documents. This will allow ample entropy to make any guessing unfeasable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [UUID's](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files) as idenification for filenames in CarrierWave which will make guessing filenames near to impossible due to the nature and concept of [UUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

Comment: could I have an example please?

Comment: Did you see the link on the first UUID keyword? https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files

Answer (score -1):

Just redefine `store_dir` in your uploader class.

```
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{rand 500}_#{model.id}"
  end
```

Well, don't use `rand 500` in a real application of course.

Comment: While adding randoms is good, the entropy of `rand 500` is rather low, why use half measures when you can rely on proper UUIDs as filenames?

Comment: This an example on how to do that with CarrierWave. Of course you're not supposed to use `rand 500` in a real application :p.

Comment: Downvoting somebody without asking anything else or leaving a comment explaining is just MEH.

Comment: Yeah. Doesn't really matter anyway, that's just somebody with an unsolved problem.